# Passing dynamically generated textbox values to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some form in which I want to automatically generate new textbox on + button click and then I want to submit it to CandidateRegister action method in Candidates controller.

```
@model SourceTreeITMatchmaking.Models.CandidateRegisterViewModel
```

*Candidates View*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CandidateRegister", "Candidates"))
{
     <div id="myTechnologies">
             <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedMyTechnologies.Technology, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="C#, Java, Sql Server..."})
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mt60">
        <div class="clearfix">
                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-large pull-right" value="Register candidate!">
        </div>
}
```

*jQuery function to add new Textbox on (+) button click*

```
$("#add-technology-candidate").click(function () {
    var firstDiv = $(' <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0;"> ' +
        ' <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="C#, Java, Sql Server..." /> </div>');
    $("#myTechnologies").append(firstDiv.append(deleteButton));
});
```

*One propery of my CandidateRegisterViewModel which I use for strongly typed model*

```
public class CandidateRegisterViewModel
{
    public SelectedMyTechnologies SelectedMyTechnologies { get; set; }
}
```

/*Property that I use in CandidateRegisterViewModel*/

```
public class SelectedMyTechnologies
{
        public List<string> Technology { get; set; }
}
```

Long story short-> I want to generate textbox on (#add-technology-candidate) button click and then pass user entered data as a list to my controller. As my code is right now, I can only pass data from first textbox (not dynamically generated one). How should I change jQuery method to support both types?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your property is `List<string>` you can just give the dynamically created textboxes a name attribute matching the property

```
 <input type="text" name="SelectedMyTechnologies.Technology" ... />
```

Note this will only work for collections of `string` or value types. For collections of complex objects, you need to include indexers as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796)

Comment: Thanks. I don't get the whole idea though. If I had a view model with string and SelectList properties instead of single list in SelectedMyTechnologies how would it look then? How does indexer work for this specified case?

Comment: Did you even look at the link I gave you? At the moment your dynamically creating inputs without a `name` attribute so they do not post back. For collections of simple types, the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind (say) List<string> Address` if you have multiple inputs with `<input name="Address" />`. But if your property was say `List<Address>` where `Address` contains properties then you would need `<input name="[0]Address.Street" />`,  `<input name="[1]Address.Street" />` etc.

Comment: Yes of course I saw the link You gave me, sorry for trouble. Now I understand completely :) Thanks